# Check condition on all elements of an array

Tags: solidity, dapps, arrays

I need to check if all elements in an array (`uint[]`) are in a specific range.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. This is what I came up with at the moment:

```
contract MyContract {

    /* ... */

    function pickNumbers(uint[5] memory _stdNumbers, uint memory _specialNumber) public {

        for(uint i=0; i<_stdNumbers.length; i++) {
            require(_stdNumbers[i] > 0 && _stdNumbers[i] < 70, "Invalid standard number");
        }

        require(_specialNumber > 0 && _specialNumber < 27, "Invalid special number");

        // DO SOMETHING

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the size of 5 really constant ? or did you put it there for the example ?

Comment: It is constant, the caller should put exactly 5 standard numbers + a special number as input. (edit: I could probably change it in the for loop too)

Comment: Alright, well with memory arrays there is not much more to do I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there was something similar to `array.every(condition)` of JavaScript, that's why I posted a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's about it.  You can save some gas though:

```
function pickNumbers(uint[5] memory _stdNumbers, uint memory _specialNumber) public {


    for(uint i=0; i<5;) {
        require(_stdNumbers[i] > 0 && _stdNumbers[i] < 70, "Invalid standard number");
        unchecked { i += 1 }
    }

    require(_specialNumber > 0 && _specialNumber < 27, "Invalid special number");

    // DO SOMETHING

}
```

or if its just 5, it would probably be most optimal to just write 5 require statements

```
  require(_stdNumbers[0] > 0 && _stdNumbers[0] < 70, "Invalid standard number");
  require(_stdNumbers[1] > 0 && _stdNumbers[1] < 70, "Invalid standard number");
  ....
```

Comment: Very helpful, I didn't know that unchecked block existed, allowing to avoid unnecessary under/overflow checks in a for loop. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I too love this trick with unchecked.

Comment: You can use `i++;` instead of `i += 1;`.